# R horizontal barplot with axis labels split between two axis

Tags: r, bar-chart

I have a horizontal barplot, with zero in the middle of the x-axis and would like the name for each bar to appear on the same side as the bar itself. The code I am using is:

```
abun<-data$av.slope
species<-data$Species
cols <- c("blue", "red")[(abun > 0)+1] 
barplot(abun, main="Predicted change in abundance", horiz=TRUE,
xlim=c(-0.04,0.08), col=cols, names.arg=species, las=1, cex.names=0.6)
```

I have tried creating two separate axes and the names do appear on the desired side for each bar, but are not level with the appropriate bar. I will try and upload an image of the barplot, am still very new to R, apologies if I am missing something basic!

[barplot1- names in correct position but all on one axis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u5uNi.png)

[barplot2- names on both sides of plot but not in line with appropriate bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MqrIk.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can accomplish this using `mtext`:

#### generate data

Since you didn't include your data in the question I generated my own dummy data set. If you post a `dput` of your data, we could adapt this solution to your data.

```
set.seed(123)
df1 <- data.frame(x = rnorm(20),
                   y = LETTERS[1:20])
df1$colour <- ifelse(df1$x < 0, 'blue', 'red')
```

#### make plot

```
bp <- barplot(df1$x, col = df1$colour, horiz = T)
mtext(side = ifelse(df1$x < 0, 2, 4),
      text = df1$y,
      las = 1,
      at = bp,
      line = 1)
```

[image]